# Overriding an internal abstract method in another assembly

Tags: c#, .net, overriding, visibility

Im currently working on a c# project that uses another .net library. This library does (amongst other things) parse a sequence into a tree. All items are of some type that inherits from the abstract class `Sequence`. I needed to alter the behaviour slightly and subclassed `Sequence` myself (lets call it `MySequence`). After the tree was created, I could replace some tree nodes with objects of my own class.

Now, a new version of the library was published, and a `Copy` function with the following signature was introduced:

```
internal abstract Sequence Copy();
```

I tried to adopt my code to the new version and override it, but whatever I am doing, I get the two errors:

> `MySequence` does not implement inherited abstract member '`Sequence.Copy()`'
>   and:
>   `MySequence.Copy()`': no suitable method found to override

This makes sense, since it is abstract (--> it must be overwritten) and internal (--> it can not be overwritten, due to hidden visibility from outside the assembly)

So, the problem is, I understand why this is happening, but dont know what to do against it. It is crucial for my project to subclass `Sequence`.

And what I also dont understand is, why the `internal abstract` modfier is allowed in the first place as it basically permits any subclassing of the whole class from outside the assembly!?

Is there any way to solve this? Via reflection or something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303591/internal-abstract-methods-why-would-anyone-have-them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you are out of luck without altering the library. There may be a subclass of Sequence that does implement Copy, which you can derive from in the new version. But it is likely that the Copy method is need in other parts of the library to create clones.

Comment: I already though about this. Looks like this is my only alternative.

Comment: In the end, that solved the problem: I just subclassed a non-abstract class that was very similar to my implementation and that also inherited from ``Sequence``. I overwrote all methods to get the same behaviour as in the past. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 4):

This modifier means that the class can only be inherited in the assembly that defined it.

There is no way around that.

Comment: One question stays: why is ``internal abstract`` allowed in c#? Can it really be intented by anyone to introduce a method to make the class 'non-subclassable' from outside? Wouldnt it make more sense to use a class modifyer for this?

Comment: @Philip: What would that modifier be called? `internal abstract` is perfectly fine.

Comment: In fact, I wish that C# allowed `private abstract` members too.

Comment: @Philip Daubmeier: I answered that. It is allowed to prevent anyone from deriving directly from the type containing that `internal abstract` member.

Comment: @SLaks. How can `private abstract` members be useful? I might be mistaken here, but I believe an instance of a type containing such a member can never be instantiated....

Comment: @JBS: I had an `abstract` type that I only wanted to be inherited by nested classes.

Comment: @SLaks: I meant, that if someone would like to declare his class non-subclassable, he could make an ``internal abstract class Bla`` instead declaring a ``public abstract class Bla`` with some member ``internal abstract void Member``... I guess the programmers of this library just didnt think about that whole thing.

Comment: @Philip: That would make the entire class `internal`.  There are very good reasons to make a class that can be used, but not inherited, outside your assembly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you had some very good points there. I know you were the first to answer it, but I will accept CodeNaked's, because he gave me the hint to solve that whole problem in the end.

Comment: @PhilipDaubmeier They should make all the ***instance constructors*** of such a class `internal` (or `private`). It's fine for the class itself to be `public`. Instance constructors of abstract classes are only called by the instance constructors in the inheriting classes.

Answer (score 1):

If a library has a type with a member with the modifiers `internal abstract`, I conclude that the developers of that library didn't want anyone to derive their own type from that type. You cannot work around this.

You can consider whether this was done deliberately. You should ask the publishers. It might be a mistake, in which case the publishers will probably issue a fix. If it is done deliberately, you should come up with an alternative solution without deriving from that type.
EDIT: Or perhaps they intended for you to derive only from derived types in the same assembly that already implement that member.