# Why can't I derive from GridViewRowPresenterBase?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Why can't I derive from GridViewRowPresenterBase?

```
public class GridViewRowPresenterEx : GridViewRowPresenterBase
{
    protected override void OnColumnPropertyChanged(GridViewColumn c, string s)
    {
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following compile errors:

> 'GridViewRowPresenterEx' does not implement inherited abstract member
>   System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.GridViewRowPresenterBase.OnColumnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.Controls.GridViewColumn,
>   string)'
>
> 'GridViewRowPresenterEx.OnColumnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.Controls.GridViewColumn,
>   string)': no suitable method found to override

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `OnColumnPropertyChanged()` method exposed by [GridViewRowPresenterBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.gridviewrowpresenterbase.aspx) is `internal abstract` (you can see it in the source code [here](http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/Dotnetfx_Win7_3@5@1/Dotnetfx_Win7_3@5@1/3@5@1/DEVDIV/depot/DevDiv/releases/Orcas/NetFXw7/wpf/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Primitives/GridViewRowPresenterBase@cs/1/GridViewRowPresenterBase@cs)).

Unfortunately, [there is no way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6266229/464709) to implement an `internal abstract` method outside of its original assembly. It looks like `GridViewRowPresenterBase` was designed to only be derivable by other classes in `PresentationFramework.dll`.

Comment: It would have been helpful if they had changed the accessibility of their instance constructor from `protected` to `internal`. That would send a signal "we thought about this and we won't allow inheritance from other assemblies". The compiler-generated default instance constructor will be `protected` by default.