# Can't Inherit an interface with hidden methods

Tags: c#, .net, class, interface

I am writing a C# Class Library using VS 2010. I'm referencing a DLL that I believe was written with an unmanaged compiler because I don't believe you can mark a method as private in .NET managed code.

When I attempt to inherit an interface from the referenced DLL and Implement the Abstract Class, it complains that I didn't implement a specific method. I tried manually but the signatures obviously don't match because it says no suitable method found to override.

'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' does not implement inherited abstract member 'xxx.xxx.xxx.Foo(string, xxx.xxx.xxx)'

I searched using the object browser and realized it's not available to me. It's hidden probably because it wasn't meant to not be inherited?

I have to figure out a way to make this work. How can I find the correct signature?

Thank you in advance for you help on this matter
mj

Comment: You've got it backwards. You inherit from an abstract class and implement an interface. Please post some code so we can see what issue you're having.

Comment: We need to see the real declarations, including all modifiers.  It's impossible to help otherwise.  (The real error message helps, too)

Comment: Can you please post some code. The interface declaration as well as your code to implement the interface.

Comment: CORRECTION: I searched using the object browser and realized it is NOT available to me. It's hidden probably because it wasn't meant to be inherited?

Comment: If it was "written with an unmanaged compiler" [sic] then it wouldn't be possible for you to add a reference to it and start implementing interfaces and abstract classes from it. Also note that implementing an interface and an abstract class are two different things, you don't (necessarily) do one to do the other. Also note that if you say it is "available to you" then that probably implies that you should be able to use it, which you are clearly not. Can you please post some more specific code?

Comment: CORRECTION: it's an abstract class. I typed my message faster than I could think. Too many hours at work.

Comment: The error message indicates there's an `abstract` method you need to implement. Are you saying that method is `private` (or `internal`?) inside the DLL you reference? It is not a very clear question.

Comment: The situation with a public class with an internal abstract member is mentioned in the thread [internal abstract methods. Why would anyone have them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303591/internal-abstract-methods-why-would-anyone-have-them). Don't know if this is what you have.

Comment: My apologies for not be clear. Let me try again.

I inherited an abstract class. 
Implemented the abstract class
When I compile, I get an error

MyField' does not implement inherited abstract member 'Field.SetField(string, Field)'

It's not available via object browser.

Comment: if its marked as internal the Implement Abstract Class will implement it. I don't know what it is marked as nor to I understand why its not available

Comment: It looks to me like that member must be a property and not a field. Again posting some code would help a lot.

Comment: Other threads: [Overriding an internal abstract method in another assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266229/) and [Why can't I derive from GridViewRowPresenterBase?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871839/).

Answer (score 0):

My guess based on the limited information you provide is that the DLL has a class that looks something like:

```
namespace Xxx
{
  public abstract class TheirType
  {
    // accessible instance constructor
    protected TheirType()
    {
    }

    // inaccessible abstract member
    internal abstract void TheMethod()
    {
    }
  }
}
```

This lets people first think that they can derive from `TheirType` outside the assembly because that constructor is accessible. But they have no chance of implementing the abstract member `TheMethod` because an `internal` member is inaccessible in another assembly.

It would have been more friendly if the authors of `TheirType` either

- decide their type should allow inheritance from the outside, and therefore make `TheMethod` either `public`, `protected internal`, or `protected`; OR
- make all instance constructors inaccessible from the outside, i.e. `internal` or `private` to make it obvious that they don't allow people to inherit `TheirType` from other assemblies.

Comment: Thanks Jeppe for your response, makes sense.