# What is the purpose of internal abstract method in a abstract class?

Tags: c#

What is the purpose of internal abstract method in a abstract class?
why to make an abstract method internal in a abstract class? if we want to restrict abstract class outside the assembly why don't we just make abstract internal class.
Is there any other logic behind it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Adding `internal` member to a `public` abstract class makes it impossible to inherit that `abstract` class outside of assembly it was declared in. But the class itself as well as all derived classes can still be used (as the types are `public`) outside of declaring assembly.

Let's say you have an abstract class:

```
public abstract AMyClass
{
    public string DoSomething()
    {
        return DoSomethingInternal();
    }

    internal abstract string DoSomethingInternal();
}
```

And another public class that inherits it, declared in the same assembly

```
public sealed MyClass : AMyClass
{
    internal override string DoSomethingInternal()
    {
        return "Hey from MyClass!";
    }
}
```

You could still create an instance of `MyClass` in different assemblies, but you won't be able to implement your own class that derives from `AMyClass`, because you won't be able to implement abstract `DoSomethingInternal` method.

Comment: Thanks Marcin for your reply, But can you plz just explain your these lines...       But the class itself as well as all derived classes can still be used (as the types are public) outside of declaring assembly.

Comment: I can't believe that after more than 20 years of programming, I did not know that. This just really helped me solve a difficult problem.

Comment: I have a .NET Framework 4.8 project with an empty class that derives from the `public abstract class ServerProtocol` (`System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocol`) and that class has `internal abstract` members, yet it compiles fine for me in VS2019, and ILSpy shows it exists. I only get a runtime `TypeLoadException` when I try to instantiate it in LinqPad 5. Whereas older versions of VS *do* block compilation. This is weird...

Answer (score 7):

> The internal keyword is an access modifier for types and type members.
>   Internal types or members are accessible only within files in the same
>   assembly, as in this example

```
public class BaseClass 
{
    // Only accessible within the same assembly
    internal static int x = 0;
}
```

Now in your case this is something like:

```
public abstract BaseClass
{
   internal abstract void Print();
}
```

Now, in this case all the class which are in same assembly of BaseClass, will be able to override the Print method of BaseClass. But outside of the assembly classes will only be able to override public members. like

```
 public abstract BaseClass
 {
    internal abstract void Print();
    public abstract void Hello();
 }
```

Classes outside of the assembly of BaseClass won't be able to use this class as one of member of this class is internal. Solution is create sub class in same assembly of BaseClass and use that class outside the assembly.

I suggest you to read the access modifier concept in c# from C# in depth by @john skeet.

Comment: Thanks Mukund, But after making a abstract method internal,  I am not able to derive that abstract class  outside the assembly.So, how will i override it's hello method.

Comment: is your class Public? You will be able to access this class outside of assembly only if when BaseClass is public.@ArunBisht

Comment: namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public abstract class Class1
    {

         internal abstract void show(); 
         public abstract void hide();      
    }
    
     
}                                                                                                                                I am not able to derive this class outside the assembly.. Giving error ...          'ConsoleApplication1.Program' does not implement inherited abstract member 'ClassLibrary1.Class1.show()'

Comment: build the solution. add reference again, and can you please add code here how you are inheriting this Class1? I don't see any problem with your above code. @ArunBisht

Comment: using ClassLibrary1;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program : Class1
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           
        }

        public override void hide()
        {
        }
      
    
    }
     
}

Comment: Adding internal member to a public abstract class makes it impossible to inherit that abstract class outside of assembly it was declared in. So if you declare any method as internal inside any class then you won't be able to use that class outside the assembly. This is very tricky question infact. Solution is create another sub class in same assembly of Base class and use subclass outside the assembly. I hope it helps.

Comment: @ArunBisht Take a look at my answer i think it answers your question

Comment: @ArunBisht for example check kyle answer.

Comment: ok fine Mukund, if internal abstract is restricting it outside the assembly then      why don't we simply make the abstract class internal..

Comment: Yes you can do this, there is no harm but, I suppose this method prevents external inheritance while retaining visibility.

Comment: check this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303591/internal-abstract-methods-why-would-anyone-have-them

Comment: ok, i have read that article. if the goal is that "the original programmer wanted to make a derived control available to client code. But prevent the client from inheriting and messing with the virtual method."   in that case we can even make abstract  class internal rather than making method internal

Comment: Mukund, do you feel that we have got cleared all our doubts on this topic. As I don't feel so.

Comment: I think so. what's your doubt now? :)

Comment: what can we achieve by making an abstract method internal which we can't achieve using making that abstract class internal..

Comment: In case of making method internal, It will show your class outside but you can't derive it..                                                                                                    In case of making the class internal will not show that class outside the library.  (It this the only difference)...

Comment: Yes, if you make class internal you will not be able to access that class outside the assembly, but if you make your claas public and method internal abstract, you will be able to access the class outside the assembly, but you won't be able to derive from it. I hope it's clear now.

Comment: Thanks Mukund, ,  I had a good conversation with you and i appreciate you  for sparing you time for me. But i have to accept the answer of Marcin..

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you have a code in your project

lets say its a console app and we call it as ConsoleApplication1

```
      namespace ConsoleApplication1
      {
           class Program
           {
              static void Main(string[] args)
              {}

            }

          public abstract class MyAbsClass
          {
              public string DoSomething()
              {
                 return DoSomethingInternal();

              }

           internal abstract string DoSomethingInternal();

           public abstract string DoSomethingExternal();

          }

          public  class MyClass:MyAbsClass
          {
                 internal override string DoSomethingInternal(){}                   
                 public override string DoSomethingExternal(){}

          }
       }
```

and now you have  (lets say another consoleApp called ConsoleApplication2) you build your consoleapplication1 and add reference to it

```
  using ConsoleApplication1;

  namespace ConsoleApplication2
  {
     class Program
     {
         static void Main(string[] args)
         {
         }
     }
class NewClass : MyAbsClass
{

    public override string DoSomethingExternal()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
  }
 }
```

Now when you build this you get an error `Error 1   'ConsoleApplication2.NewClass' does not implement inherited abstract member 'ConsoleApplication1.MyAbsClass.DoSomethingInternal()`

Why this error?? because compiler is telling you that when you declare member as internal ,the class which is in the same assembly ie (ConsoleApplication1) can have access it.So no matter how many class you create in ConsoleApplication2 you wont be able to access it because it is declared **internal**.