# Why is not inheriting from class containing internal abstract method from another assembly error?

Tags: c#, abstract-class

Let's assume we have these two definitions

```
// assembly A
public abstract class A
{
    internal abstract void func();
}

// assembly B
public class B : A
{
    // internal override void func()
}
```

The error message says "B does not implement abstract member A.func()". I think that's bad design decision for reasons which I will try to describe in this post. I would be thankful for any insights for why the current design was chosen by creators of C# language. If I made internal members into Roslyn then I would surely create at least error saying something like "B cannot inherit from A which contains internal member" or ideally new keyword `closed` which forbids inheriting from another assembly without need of internal abstract member. Why? For these reasons:

a) Abstract class A may contain many members. Then I decide to inherit from class A in another assembly and after few days of work I implement most of its methods fixing one error by one. Then I suddenly see last error message saying that internal member is not implemented which IS NOT RECOVERABLE. This seems just wrong.

b) B is underlined although the problem is obviously that I am trying to inherit from A! Compiler should tell me that I am doing something wrong immediately without any of checking accessibility modifiers of every member in base class.

c) It is great that I can restrict inheriting from my base class from another assembly! But what if I want to restrict inheritance from my class which does not need any internal member? Then I am forced to add internal abstract member which is never used! I don't understand why people who created C# language just didn't make another keyword `closed` or whatever other name which would forbid inheritance from another assembly.

d) Adding internal member should not be breaking change outside of current assembly. I strongly believe in that. That's why if I designed C# I would prefer `closed` keyword. My feeling is that internal abstract members were not implemented properly.

Comment: Why do you need this? If you derive from an abstract class, you're supposed to implement the abstract methods it exposes (unless the derived class is also marked as `abstract`). Why is this an issue to you? I don't see why anyone would expect the compiler to allow you to inherit an abstract class without implementing its abstract members, that wouldn't make any sense. Btw, you can seal a class (declare the class as `sealed`) so it can't be inherited but as far as I understand your issue, you only care about `internal` correct? If so, why is your class `public` if you don't need it outside?

Comment: My problem is that I see the problem late. There can be 99 non internal abstract methods and one internal abstract method in base class. Then I do a lot of work by implementing those 99 methods and everything seems fine - I am fixing one error after another. Then I suddenly see that I can't fix last error because it's not public. Is it expected of me that I check accessibility modifiers of all those members although I don't have access to that code base?

Comment: Nothing says that you have to ignore errors until it's too late.

Comment: There is 100 error messages about members which aren't implemented! Maybe only one of them is internal abstract method, all others are fine. After I implement 56 of those then I see that the one I want to implement now is internal abstract method which literally throws away all of my work

Comment: Do you really check accessibility modifiers of all members from abstract class after you try to implement it? And even if you do so, the another question is whether it should be expected. Programmers are lazy and it just seems unnecessary. The problem is not that internal member is not implemted. It's internal detail of that base class that there is internal member. The problem is that I try to implement class which forbids inheriting from another assembly

Comment: You could hit alt+Enter and generate all those empty implementations (assuming VS of course). Then you can see if that would work or not. In theory you should just be able to make the internal method public. Is this not a possibility in your case?

Comment: You really suggest that behaviour of compiler should rely on alt+enter shortcut from Visual Studio? I think that it should be done correctly without need of any further actions. I don't like that feature because it messes up my code (order of methods)

Comment: Why do you have code in an abstract class before implementing the abstract members? Don't get me wrong here, I understand the frustration. I don't know anything about why they chose to do it that way, so I can't provide detail on that. However I think maybe your class might be a bit overloaded and or should be split into multiple classes (I don't know what you're working on, this is just an idea). The idea with VS was just something to help you find these annoying errors in a fast way, it's of course not a perfect solution.

Comment: It is from library and I don't have access to that code. Author meant to not allow inheriting from that base class from another assembly. That is something that should be visible even by intellisense! I tried to inherit from it and first implemented all abstract methods. My work is completely ruined by this behaviour and I don't feel like I did anything really wrong. Yeah I could decompile that base class to check whether there is internal abstract member but who really does that?

Comment: Sometimes we as a programmers have to use badly designed apis and compiler should help. Not throw away all of my work

Comment: It was probably intentional then - the author doesn't want you to be able to do that. Again, I don't know _why_ it is this way and I also don't know why the author wanted to prevent that. Btw, [closely related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28688813/what-is-the-purpose-of-internal-abstract-method-in-a-abstract-class).

Comment: I'm guessing that the c# design team had more important things to do with their limited time and budget. At least, that's the usual answer to the question "why doesn't language x implement feature y?"

Comment: Your feature request for better compiler feedback (for that's really what this is) has merit, but all features [start at minus 100 points](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericgu/2004/01/12/minus-100-points/). That's why things like [issue trackers](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues) exist.